# what's the "correct" practive for designing the interface for this REST web service?

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I'm building a REST web service to manage customers and customer orders.

I'm using Eclipse 3.4 with JAX-RS (Apache Wink 1.0) on WebSphere 7.

I have a web project defined in web.xml like so ...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache....RestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mydomain.ws.CustomerWS</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
/***/
</servlet>
```

... which gives me a URL like `http://.../ws/customers` that returns all customers.

Now what I need to do is have something like `http://.../ws/orders` that returns all orders.

**My questions are,**

I want to add a second web service -- what do I add to the web.xml so that new web service is visible?  or am I supposed to create a totally new web project for my second "orders" web service?

or any other ideas?  Not sure how to design this "correctly".

Thanks, Rob

Comment: You might want to follow the setup instructions here: http://incubator.apache.org/wink/1.0/html/JAX-RS%20Getting%20Started.html.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did all that.  The link doesn't answer the question which is about adding a second web service.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you add your second class as a resource in the `getClasses` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Wink, but assuming it's JAX-RS-compatible, you should not need any web.xml changes.
If your container is JAX-RS aware,

- then annotating your 2nd class with @Path should automatically deploy it
- else you can add that new resource class to your REST Application, e.g. based on the example you linked and speculating on your resource class names:

  ```
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
      Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
      classes.add(CustomersResource.class); 
      classes.add(OrdersResource.class);
      return classes;
  }
  ```